# Adding arrays to a larger array in the form of a grid?

Tags: java, arrays, opengl, 3d, terrain

I am attempting to implement infinite terrain generation into my OpenGL Java 3D game. I have a method that generates a "chunk" of terrain using Perlin Noise. All the data (vertices, indices etc.) are stored in a class called MeshData.

My approach to this (correct me if there is a better one) is to detect when the player has moved off the center chunk, based on a 3x3 grid of chunks. Therefore, only 9 chunks are being processed at once. My problem is that each chunk generates its own set of vertices, indices, heights etc. and I am trying to find a way to "merge" all these separate arrays into one master array, to only render one object. This way, all the gaps between the chunks will disappear due to interpolation.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private void join(MeshData data, int id) {
    // TODO: Join data to our own data at x, z
    int count = (VERTEX_COUNT * VERTEX_COUNT) * 3;
    int xPos = (id % 3) * count;
    int zPos = (id / 3) * count;
    for (int z = zPos; z < zPos + count; z++) {
        for (int x = xPos; x < xPos + count; x++) {

        }
    }
}
```

ID is a number between 0 and 8, in a grid of chunks like so:

```
0, 1, 2,
3, 4, 5,
6, 7, 8
```

and therefore xPos and yPos are the starting positions in the main array that covers all the vertices of all chunks.

This is as far as I got, I cannot seem to work out how to finish this. I have been at this for a few days but keep getting stuck. Any help/advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Code which shows how each chunks vertices are generated:

```
private void generateChunk(int id, float x, float z) {
    int count = VERTEX_COUNT * VERTEX_COUNT;
    float[] vertices = new float[count*3];
    float[] normals = new float[count*3];
    float[] textureCoords = new float[count*2];
    int vertexPointer = 0;
    int intX = (int)x;
    int intZ = (int)z;
    for (int i = 0; i < VERTEX_COUNT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < VERTEX_COUNT; j++) {
            vertices[vertexPointer * 3] = ((float) j / ((float) VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * CHUNK_SIZE) + x;
            float height = getHeight(j + intX, i + intZ);
            heights[j][i] = height; // <--
            vertices[vertexPointer * 3 + 1] = height; // <--
            vertices[vertexPointer * 3 + 2] = ((float) i / ((float) VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * CHUNK_SIZE) + z;
            Vector3f normal = calculateNormal(j + intX, i + intZ);
            normals[vertexPointer * 3] = normal.x;
            normals[vertexPointer * 3 + 1] = normal.y;
            normals[vertexPointer * 3 + 2] = normal.z;
            textureCoords[vertexPointer * 2] = ((float) j / ((float) VERTEX_COUNT - 1)) + x;
            textureCoords[vertexPointer * 2 + 1] = ((float) i / ((float) VERTEX_COUNT - 1)) + z;
            vertexPointer++;
        }
    }
    join(new MeshData(vertices, textureCoords, indices).setNormals(normals), id);
}
```

UPDATE:

I have made some progress with this. All of the vertices, normals and texture coordinates are working as they should. I am now having issues calculating the indices for the whole terrain as opposed to just one chunk. I believe this code only needs to be done once (rather than per chunk), so i removed it from the generateChunk() method. Only problem is the terrain looks like the photo below and I am unsure why.

```
    int VERTEX_COUNT = 32 * 9;
    indices = new int[(6 * ((VERTEX_COUNT) - 1) * ((VERTEX_COUNT) - 1))];
    int pointer = 0;
    for (int gz = 0; gz < (VERTEX_COUNT) - 1; gz++) {
        for (int gx = 0; gx < (VERTEX_COUNT) - 1; gx++) {
            int topLeft = ((gz * (VERTEX_COUNT)) + gx);
            int topRight = topLeft + 1;
            int bottomLeft = (((gz + 1) * (VERTEX_COUNT)) + gx);
            int bottomRight = bottomLeft + 1;
            indices[pointer++] = topLeft;
            indices[pointer++] = bottomLeft;
            indices[pointer++] = topRight;
            indices[pointer++] = topRight;
            indices[pointer++] = bottomLeft;
            indices[pointer++] = bottomRight;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose you should start by describing what data you have (both in terms of logic and layout), what data you want to get as a result, as well as why you want to get that result. I'm not sure I get what interpolation you're talking about, as well as what gaps are in question - are your vertices not tightly packed? Are they have height difference on so vertices on the same position have different height in adjacent chunks? There is also a half-chunk shift approach with which you can get 7 chunks loaded instead of 9, but it may be harder to implement.

Comment: @keltar added generation code

Comment: Unless code is really big, please avoid using external link and edit code into question instead (external links are not permanent, or may be not accessible in some countries, etc.). Simplest solution would be creating 9 times bigger arrays and copying entire contents of `vertices`, `texcoords` and `normals`, and for `indices` adding avalanche shift on each chunk (just adding shift to index, and on next chunk increasing shift by `(VERTEX_COUNT-1)*(VERTEX_COUNT-1)*6`). I'm still not sure it is benefitial to merge this arrays though, what's the purpose?

Comment: @keltar the purpose was because when generating and rendering 9 separate chunks, there was gaps between the differing heights between the chunks. I assumed by joining the chunks together into one main chunk, these gaps would disappear

Comment: @keltar your solution for the indices doesn't seem to be working, perhaps I am implementing it wrong. Could you explain further?

Comment: No it isn't really related. Just merging to one mesh will produce the same result. I suppose your problem is on height difference - each chunk generated independently, and the "same" vertex on two adjacent chunks have different height value. To sew these holes you need to go through bounding edges and set height to the same value - either one or, or interpolated between chunks.

Comment: Something like `int shift = 0; const int shift_adj = (VERTEX_COUNT-1)*(VERTEX_COUNT-1)*6; int[] new_indices = new[shift_adj*9]; for(int c = 0; c != 9; ++c) { for(int i = 0; i != shift_adj; ++i) { new_indices[c*shift_adj+i] = chunk[c].indices[i] + shift; } shift += shift_adj; }`, if you just linearly copying vertex attributes (positions, texcoords, ...).